# ESP8266 - Disconnect from network via AP (in WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA))

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I've managed to get an ESP8266 to act as both access point and station. It can now connect to a network whilst also available for direct connections.

E.g.

```
WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);
WiFi.softAP(apSsid, apPassword);
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
```

Whilst connected to the Access Point I'd like to disconnect the station whilst maintaining the Access Point however using:

```
WiFi.disconnect(false);
```

Disconnects the client from the Access Point (even though softAP has its own softAPdisconnect()).

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks

C